# Edit a cell only with Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to eliminate user error in order to make my sheet sustainable from a maintenance perspective. I built a Google Sheet that is a task tracker which logs which user checked off a task. How do I lock a cell so that it may be edited ONLY by the script (the Effective User (me)), and not by manually inputting data (NOT by the Active User). If someone inputs data into a cell, it becomes not empty, and the log is shifted or otherwise corrupted. I've tried locking the sheet/cells, but then the active user can't log ANY information, even though they're using the script to log it. How can I lock a cell so that it may be edited by the effective user but not the active user?

SEE ATTACHED EXAMPLE:
Column A may be edited by User, which prompts script to fill in columns D and E.
Columns D and E should ONLY be edited by the script; no user should be able to type into those columns.
Columns B and C may not be edited by User, as they must remain the same always.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheet]

Help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that desire of control, I'd suggest the best solution would be a web app limiting input to the specified fields (perhaps using a dhtmlxgrid)

Comment: Thanks, John!! Do you know if I'm able to do this even in Google Sheets though? Their JavaScript seems finicky with what it can and can not do...

Comment: This may help [link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: You can definitely use Google Apps Script to create a web app to do this.  See 
[HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as a starting point.  You could display the entire sheet or just a portion.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that out when I was first starting, but unfortunately it doesn't help what I need. If I protect the cells, then the script will say the User doesn't have access to edit those cells. I need to grant them access but only as the effective user, if that makes sense. EDIT: didn't see Karl's comment; will go check that out now, thanks!

Comment: yes you can with a webapp NOT a dialog from a custom menu. look at webapp publishing options to "run as developer"

Comment: According to my research, it looks like I can't solve my problem with a web app because my script uses functions such as getActiveSheet(), which are not available for use within web apps. Is this correct?

Comment: a work-around: How do I program the following DATA VALIDATION rule: "if you're trying to enter text into column D, row i, but cell Ai is neither "Yes" nor "No", you may not update cell Di."

Comment: @vic you are incorrect in your assumption. The web app is mean to be an interface for the users, on it's own it will not be doing anything with the Spreadsheet. When you create a web app you need to think of your script as made from 2 parts: 1) client side (the web app in the .html) and 2) server side (what you wrote in the .gs files). The server side can do everything without problem and you call the server side functions with `google.script.run` (check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run))

Comment: thanks for your helpful comments!
I've chosen to use the data validation, as I'm trying to keep the program as simple as possible, and installed 2 rules: D text must be email, and E text must be date. In this way, it will prevent anyone from accidentally typing anything except for a full email address or time stamp, which will prevent user error of accidentally pressing a key into those cells. Thanks for your help!